# Реализация байт буффера C#

Tags: c#

Как можно нормальным образом разделить строки в массиве байт и потом их считать?
Например

```
w = new BinaryWriter(m);
public void WriteUTF8String(string val, bool nullTerminated = true)
{
   if (nullTerminated)
      val += '\0';

   w.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val));
}
```

В w байты, записать можно бесконечное кол-во строк, как потом их можно, считать по нормальному?

Готовая функция как я понимаю читать полностью до конца

```
public string ReadString()
{
    return r.ReadString();
}
```

Как я понимаю нужно читать массив байт до тех пор пока не будет обнаружен разделитель типа '\0'?

Comment: А чем вам `BinaryWriter.Write(string)` плох? Он пишет строку, префиксируя её длиной, затем с помощью `BinaryReader.ReadString()` это нормально считывается.